# Selecting default values for multi select list preference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, android-multiselectlistpreference

I am working on an android app where I have implemented preference activity.
I want to set more than one default values for Multi Select Preferences, how should I do it?

I want to do it programatically and not via layout

Comment: you can learn more on this topic. Go to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using :

```
listPreferenceData.setValues(defaultValue);
```

Here the defaultValue is the Set of the entry values which you wish to set as the default values.

Comment: Thank you was very helpful fellow Developer

Comment: This sets the current value when the layout is inflated, not the default values when the preference is first shown.

Answer (score 0):

Multi select ListPreference comes natively with Android from API level 11.
For more information on this please check:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/MultiSelectListPreference.html

And for example ,you can check this
http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240

Answer (score 0):

`MultiSelectListPreference` comes natively with Android from API level 11.

**setValues** method is used to set default value to MultiSelectListPreference.

```
void setValues (Set<String> values)
```

Sets the value of the key. This should contain entries in `getEntryValues()`

For example `mListPref.setValue(defaultValue);`